# Dependency Injection avoid loading everything at startup

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, mvp

I'm trying to use dependency injection with MVP injecting the required dependencies into the constructor. The problem I have is if I use dependency injection on the root MainWindowPresenter, all it's sub-presenters and their sub-presenters, views and services would be loaded at startup. As everything is loaded directly or indirectly from the MainWindowPresenter, that then means the entire application will be loaded into memory at startup.

I know it might not cost a lot in .NET to create all the objects at startup but I can't help thinking that it's a waste of memory as they are never all going to be used at the same time. There are some like AboutPresenter or HelpPresenter that may never be used at all. Am I missing or is this how dependency injection is supposed to work? Is there a way around this?

The only way I can find to get around this is to use factories which can then create the sub-presenters/views/services when needed. e.g.:

```cs
class HelpFactory : AbstractHelpFactory
{
    public IHelpPresenter Create()
    {
         IHelpService helpService = new ConcreteHelpService();
         IHelpView helpView = new ConcreteHelpView();

         HelpSearchPresenter searchPresenter = HelpSearchFactory.Create();

         return HelpPresenter(helpView, helpService, searchPresenter);
    }
}
```

Which is basically the same thing as the factories then depend on sub-factories but at least they are lighter than presenters/views/services and they don't need to load the sub-factories until they are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions (arranged from general to specific):

#### Composition root

Determine a **Composition Root**. [This is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). **This is preferable solution to compose all your dependencies**.

#### Abstract Factory

Instead of injecting dependencies you could inject factory of *similar* dependencies. This will help you to postpone dependencies creation and resolve only dependencies required for current situation. Example using [ninject.extension.factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki):

```
kernel.Bind<IDependencyFactory>().ToFactory();

kernel
    .Bind<IDependency>()
    .To<DependencyImpl1>()
    .NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IDependencyFactory f) => f.GetJob());

var abstractFactory = kernel.Get<IDependencyFactory>();

var dependency = abstractFactory.GetJob(); 

public abstract class IDependency { }
public class DependencyImpl1 : IDependency { }
 
public interface IDependencyFactory
{
    IDependency GetJob();
    Lazy<IDependency> GetLazyJob();
}
```

This will also helps to **avoid over-injection of your classes**, for example constructor over-injection

#### Aggregate Services

Instead of injection of dependencies, inject service that aggregates processing routines. Read more at [Refactoring to Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx)

#### Lazy loading

Sometimes it is necessary to defer the resolution of a dependency for reasons such being overly expensive to create during startup and/or being rarely used. In these cases, one can have a Lazy injected instead of IDependency. [Example using Ninject.Extension.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Lazy):

```
kernel
    .Bind<Lazy<IDependency>>()
    .To<Lazy<IDependency>>()
    .NamedLikeFactoryMethod((IDependencyFactory f) => f.GetLazyJob());

var abstractFactory = kernel.Get<IDependencyFactory>();

var lazyDependencyUsingFactory = abstractFactory.GetLazyJob();
```

Example using [lazy-loading](http://www.edcourtenay.co.uk/musings-of-an-idiot/2012/11/23/lazy-binding-with-ninject) w/o factory:

```
kernel
    .Bind<IDependency>()
    .To<DependencyImpl1>();
    
kernel
    .Bind(typeof (Lazy<>))
    .ToMethod(context =>
            ((ILazyLoader) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (LazyLoader<>).MakeGenericType(context.GenericArguments),
                                                    new object[] { context.Kernel })).Loader);

var lazyDependency = kernel.Get<Lazy<IDependency>>();

lazyDependency.Dump();
lazyDependency.Value.Dump();
```

**ps**: full sample available [here](https://gist.github.com/4587186)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the best approach for me is lazy loading.